# Gtk3 - How to listen to accelerators via GAction in my GtkApplication?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I did not find any good example for that, and I failed to get accelerators to work with GAction.

Would be great if someone could point me on what is wrong with my code:

```
static void
thunar_application_cb (GtkApplication *application)
{
  printf("thunar_application_cb\n");
}

static GActionEntry actions[] = {
  { "test", thunar_application_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL },
};

void activate_main_gui(GtkApplication *app)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main();
}

int main( int   argc, char *argv[] )
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.cron-asdf", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate_main_gui),NULL);

    g_action_map_add_action_entries(G_ACTION_MAP(app), actions, G_N_ELEMENTS(actions), NULL);

    const char *accels[] = {"<Ctrl>C", NULL};
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (app, "test", accels);

    int status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, NULL);
    g_object_unref (app);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Here the fixed example, which runs fine:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void callback ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data )
{
    g_print ( "<Ctrl>C pressed\n" );
}

static GActionEntry actions[] = {
  { "test", callback, NULL, NULL, NULL },
};


static void startup ( GtkApplication *app )
{
  g_action_map_add_action_entries(G_ACTION_MAP(app), actions, G_N_ELEMENTS(actions), NULL);

  const char *accels[] = {"<Ctrl>C", NULL};
  gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (app, "app.test", accels);
}

static void activate ( GtkApplication *app )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );

    gtk_window_set_application ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), GTK_APPLICATION ( app ) );
    gtk_window_set_title ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), "Hello GNOME" );

    gtk_widget_show_all ( GTK_WIDGET ( window ) );
}


int main( int   argc, char *argv[] )
{

  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new  ( "org.gtk.cron-asdf",G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
  g_signal_connect_swapped   ( app, "startup",  G_CALLBACK ( startup ),  app );
  g_signal_connect_swapped   ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( activate ), app );
  status = g_application_run ( G_APPLICATION ( app ), 0, NULL );
  g_object_unref ( app );
  return status;
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve there? Are you interested in creating a Menu where you are interested to use CTRL-C on it, or are you intended to just use CTRL-C to call that callback function?

Comment: For the first, I just want CTRL-C to trigger the callback. Later on, I as well want to add a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are interested in calling that callback and later to use a Menu as well a good approach will be something like this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void open_file_callback ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data );

static void startup ( GtkApplication *app )
{
    GMenu *menu;
    GSimpleAction *open_action;
    GActionMap *action_map;
    const gchar *const open_accels[] = { "<Ctrl>O", NULL };

    /// ***
    menu = g_menu_new ();
    open_action = g_simple_action_new ( "open", NULL);
    g_signal_connect( open_action, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( open_file_callback ),  NULL );

    /// ***
    action_map = G_ACTION_MAP ( app );
    g_action_map_add_action ( action_map, G_ACTION ( open_action ) );
    g_menu_append ( menu, "Open", "app.open");

    /// ***
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action ( GTK_APPLICATION ( app ), "app.open", open_accels );
    gtk_application_set_app_menu    ( app, G_MENU_MODEL ( menu ) );
    /// ***
    g_object_unref ( menu );
}

static void activate ( GtkApplication *app )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );

    gtk_window_set_application ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), GTK_APPLICATION ( app ) );
    gtk_window_set_title ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), "Hello GNOME" );

    gtk_widget_show_all ( GTK_WIDGET ( window ) );
}

int main ( void )
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new  ( "org.gtk.cron-asdf",G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_signal_connect_swapped   ( app, "startup",  G_CALLBACK ( startup ),  app );
    g_signal_connect_swapped   ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( activate ), app );
    status = g_application_run ( G_APPLICATION ( app ), 0, NULL );
    g_object_unref ( app );
    return status;
}

void open_file_callback ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data )
{
    ( void )action;
    ( void )parameter;
    ( void )user_data;
    g_print ( "Open File.\n" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, works fine with/without menu !  Following your example, I as well got my own one to run now.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Happy coding. If you think you need more GTK informations, please follow [My Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/MichaelB-GTK)

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll subscribe there !  ... possibly you as well have an idea for this one? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613713/gtk3-persisting-shortcuts-while-using-gsimpleaction