# gtk3 - persisting shortcuts while using GSimpleAction

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

In gtk3 there is the possibility to persist accelerator keys and pathes to file by using [gtk_accel_map](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Accelerator-Maps.html#gtk-accel-map-lookup-entry). The user is able to customize shortcuts by editing the related file.

Now I am about to replace the deprected GtkAction interface by making use of GSimpleAction.

So how can I get the required parametrs for [gtk_accel_map_add_entry](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Accelerator-Maps.html#gtk-accel-map-add-entry) out of a GSimpleAction (or out of a GActionMap?), so that I can persist it ?

I defined the GSimpleAction like that:

```
void callback ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer user_data )
{
    g_print ( "<Ctrl>k pressed\n" );
}

static GActionEntry actions[] = {
  { "test", callback, NULL, NULL, NULL },
};

... // Inside application_startup (GApplication *gapp):
  g_action_map_add_action_entries(G_ACTION_MAP(application), actions, G_N_ELEMENTS(actions), NULL);

  const char *accels[] = {"<Ctrl>k", NULL};
  gtk_application_set_accels_for_action (application, "app.test", accels);
...
```

Possibly related: Recently I learned that [gtk_accel_map will be gone in gtk4](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2375#note_817764)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `GtkAccelMap` with the `GAction` API. `GAction`, by itself, has no "presentational" information.

The accelerators are held by the `GtkApplication` instance, and you can query the with [`gtk_application_get_accels_for_action()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#gtk-application-get-accels-for-action); you will need to hold on to the list of actions you're interested on, because there is no API to iterate over the actions associated with a `GtkApplication`.

Comment: Thanks alot, 'gtk_application_get_accels_for_action()' looks promising ! I will give it a try when I have time.